# How can you tell if a suggestion was selected from JQuery UI Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a text box that is wired to JQuery UI Autocomplete. As the user types in the box my search runs via an ajax call and returns suggestions. It seems that three things can happen:

1. The autocomplete suggests options and the user selects one of them
2. The autocomplete suggests options but the user chooses to select none of them
3. The autocomplete can not make a suggestion - no match (so the list of suggestions do not display)

Dealing with all of the scenarios above, how can I tell if the user selects an option from the autocomplete?

I have looked into marking a flag when a search commences (match=false) and a select occurs (match=true) but this doesn't seem a very neat way of doing things.

Comment: Do you need to know when an option was *not* selected as well? That is, when a user enters a value that is not in the list of suggestions?

Comment: Yes, Andrew,  as my page needs to do something different when a value is entered that does not currently exist in the database.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `select` event like [@bfavaretto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517188/how-can-you-tell-if-a-suggestion-was-selected-from-jquery-ui-autocomplete/7517297#7517297) points out, but I think in this situation it's more convenient to use the `change` event:

```
$("#auto").autocomplete({
    source: ['hi', 'bye', 'foo', 'bar'],
    change: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.item) {
            $("span").text(ui.item.value);
        } else {
            $("span").text("user picked new value");
        }
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/3FX2n/

`change` fires when the field is blurred, but unlike the native `change` event, you get information about whether or not the user clicked an event (`ui.item` is null if the user did not click a suggestion).

Comment: This is a good answer if you are happy to wait for the field to blur before knowing if the item is new. Thanks for the input, Andrew.

Comment: @Andrew tat was something I was looking for but instead of asking a separate question if you could let me know it could be excellent. wat if I want to get the different value the user had typed in which was not selected from the auto complete dropdown?How do I get that?

Comment: @Gotham'sReckoning: Try `$(this).value()`

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker wudn't that give both the values together?? how can I differentiate?? between them?

Comment: @Gotham'sReckoning: If they pick a value, `ui.item` will not be `null`. If the code in the `else` block is reached, calling `$(this).val()` will just get the value in the input--you know they didn't select a value because if they had `ui.item` would not be null. Does this help? http://jsfiddle.net/0cL1e2ar/

Comment: this makes it better thanks for that but in my scenario user could add multiple values some from the autocomplete suggestion and some custom values how could I treat that separately?

Comment: @Gotham'sReckoning: That would be more involved-- you'd have to split the input and look at your source to see which ones were part of the source. Probably worth opening a new question

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker would you take a look at this question??[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26920777/how-to-get-the-user-inputted-custom-value-and-the-selected-suggestion-from-autoc

Comment: Note that the user could still manually type in the same value as one of the suggestions and this would still say "user picked new value". If you need to know whether or not the item is truly new, you'll need to manually check to see if it's in the list of suggestions (or query your data source directly).

Comment: Note that the user could still manually type in the same value as one of the suggestions and this would still say "user picked new value". If you need to know whether or not the item is truly new, you'll need to manually check to see if it's in the list of suggestions (or query your data source directly).

Answer (score 2):

When a user selects an option, the 'select' event is fired. You can listen to it and set a flag.

```
(function() {
    var optionSelected = false;
    $( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
        select: function(event, ui) { optionSelected = true; }
    });
})();
```

Comment: Thanks, cellcortex. So this is basically the flag solution that I outlined in the question. It would seem the isn't a really neat way of doing what I want. Thank you for clarifying that.

Comment: Actually this is a perfectly fine/common/elegant enough way to do things in JavaScript. The important thing to do is to wrap things in a closure.

Answer (score 1):

jQueryUI provides a [`select` event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-select), you should define it in the autocomplete options (when you apply the autocomplete to your form input).

For example (from the [docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-select)):

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
   select: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

You can access the selected item via `ui.item` from inside the event handler.