# How to get the user inputted custom value and the selected suggestion from autocomplete separately

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

I'm using jQuery autocomplete to populate suggestion for a textbox and it works perfectly. 
Trouble is when user intends to enter their own custom value. Below given code gives me the selected value:

```
 change: function(event, ui) {

    if (ui.item) 
    {
        values=values+ui.item.value;
    }
}
```

My issue far more complicated as user intends to add their own custom value which means I have to  to grab the exact value the user has typed in. As per my requirement I need to add a special character like a **?** (question mark) after every selected value from the autocomplete suggestion which has to used to do an exact search. If the user was limited to select only from the autocomplete it would have been way too easy and I could append that character inside the **if**. But how can I differentiate between custom value and suggested value?
 How can I attain this?

Comment: There's still no answer to your question because it's really hard to tell what do you actually want. What is a *custom value*? How is it different from *autocomplete suggestion*? Where should the **?** appear?

Comment: by custom value I meant values which are not present in the suggestion. For example if I want add the ZEBRA into the textbox and the given list of animals doesn't have zebra in it !

Comment: What about my other questions? Also where should the custom suggestions be saved? How should the be added? Are they saved in the same location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply make a new dropdown div, and have a script:

```
b.value = a.value
```

to constantly replicate the value typed in. Run the autocorrect on the second value but not the first. Then add an event listener to the second event that changes

```
a.value = b.value
```

Once clicked.